# Assert laravel model observer's event fired in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing, laravel-models

I'm going to write some tests for my laravel 7 controller methods (endpoints) to be sure that they fire model observer event (for example `saved` event on `Product` model)
as you now model observer events do not fire while using mass update and it's possible my teammates use a mass update (by mistake), then any event does not fire and it breaks the remaining processes
So by these tests, I can be sure that all parts that rely on model observer events work currently.

In [laravel testing document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#event-fake) mentioned that if you want to assert an event has been dispatched use this code (for example):

```
public function testOrderShipping()
{
    Event::fake();

    $order = factory(Order::class)->create();
    // Assert an event was dispatched
    Event::assertDispatched(OrderCreated::class);
}
```

Is it possible to assert model observer's event has been fired (dispatched) too?

Comment: To my knowledge, Laravel only registers the events on the observer, it can't determine what observer it is from.

Comment: I  *think* the event name you should assert was fired is `"eloquent.created: App\Models\Order"`,